# Python3.6 import paramiko stuck

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

python3.6 import paramiko gets stuck, I press ctrl+c get next errors.

runtime environment: centos7.4, 64bit

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
print("import paramiko begin")
import paramiko
print("import paramiko end")
```

errors:

```
    import paramiko
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 90, in <module>
    from paramiko.ed25519key import Ed25519Key
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/ed25519key.py", line 22, in <module>
    import nacl.signing
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nacl/signing.py", line 17, in <module>
    import nacl.bindings
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nacl/bindings/__init__.py", line 377, in <module>
    sodium_init()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nacl/bindings/sodium_core.py", line 32, in sodium_init
    ffi.init_once(_sodium_init, "libsodium")
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/nacl/bindings/sodium_core.py", line 22, in _sodium_init
    ensure(lib.sodium_init() != -1,
```

Comment: Please post your code and environment information. You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Interesting - this is a BIG problem I have had for a very long time and not been able to track it down.  This is the first I have heard of anyone else with the issue.

Answer (score -1):

seems to be related to [this](https://github.com/pyca/pynacl/issues/327#issuecomment-326798389) PyNaCl issue

For me the fix was installing PyNaCl without a wheel:

```
pip install pynacl -I --no-binary pynacl
```

Got it from [here](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1023#issuecomment-317516014)